# Last word disappears during whole word string split

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that is designed to cut a string with delineation into segments, then uses "Text to Column" to store it on a worksheet in the split segments so that they can be individually loaded into a custom popup. My issue is that it always cuts and removes the last word from the string. I am obviously missing something as I can see nothing wrong with it. Can anyone tell me why I keeping loosing the last word

```
Sub CutStringLength(ByVal NoteInput As String, ByVal ControlCall As String)
    '"NoteInput" is a string from a inputbox
    '"ControlCall" is a variable name used in sheets, controls and functions

Dim AlteredString As String
Dim InnerLoop As Long, StringLimit As Long
Dim StartString As Variant

AlteredString = ""
StringLimit = 35
StartString = Split(NoteInput, " ")

For InnerLoop = LBound(StartString) To UBound(StartString)
If InnerLoop < UBound(StartString) Then
    AlteredString = AlteredString & StartString(InnerLoop) & " "
If (Len(AlteredString) + Len(StartString(InnerLoop + 1))) > StringLimit Then
   AlteredString = AlteredString & "|"
   StringLimit = Len(AlteredString) + 35
End If
End If
Next

AlteredString = Trim(AlteredString)

Worksheets(ControlCall).Range("BS2").Value = AlteredString
Worksheets(ControlCall).Select
Range("BS2").Select

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("BS2"),DataType:=xlDelimited, _
TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, _ 
OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusnumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you want to split a long string into whole words with a 255 character limit on each segment. Is that correct?

Comment: The string limit has to be much small than 255, the string limit I have set is 35. My custom popup does not have word wrap abilities so the string has to be split and loaded as individual lines.

Comment: Or you could put a `Chr(10` line feed in at the same intervals.

Comment: The popup menu I am using is a class module I download a while back that creates a right mouse button menu to a command button in a user form and although I am getting better I am still to much of a novice at VBA to add Chr() functions to it.

Comment: Are you ever going to access `StartString(UBound(StartString)`?  It looks like your `IF` will skip that when  Index = Ubound(StartString).

Comment: Ron - Can you explain your question further?  Ubound(StartString) is index in every loop of the parent IF to compare if Innerloop has reached the end of the string.

Comment: You only concatenate `StartString(InnerLoop)` when `InnerLoop **<** UBound(StartString)`.  So when `InnerLoop **=** UBound(StartString)`, that step gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Use InStrRev to find the first space backwards from your maximum position.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim pcs As Variant
    Cells(1, "B") = splitString(Cells(1, "A").Value2)
    pcs = Split(Cells(1, "B").Value2, Chr(124))
    Cells(2, "B").Resize(1, UBound(pcs) + 1) = pcs
End Sub

Function splitString(str As String, Optional n As Long = 60)
    Dim p As Long, w As Long, words() As Variant

    Do While Len(Trim(str)) > n And CBool(InStr(1, str, Chr(32)))
        p = InStrRev(str, Chr(32), n)
        ReDim Preserve words(w)
        words(w) = Trim(Left(str, p))
        str = Trim(Mid(str, p))
        w = w + 1
    Loop

    ReDim Preserve words(w)
    words(w) = Trim(str)
    splitString = Join(words, Chr(124))
End Function
```

There is no need to resort to TextToColumns. You can split your adjusted string into a variant array and pass the values directly into the worksheet.

[image]

Comment: The input box is strictly used to add a note on a account and is stored under the account holder as a permanent record on a worksheet. The popup menu is populated dynamically only when the user right clicks on the individual account command button and the string is then added to the top of the Menu as a note. Since the menu's class module was not build to handle Chr() functions I have to load segments of the string into the menu as "additem" and found that load an array was very glitchy. Storing the note on the work sheet in the segments and then loading them individually was my best path.